# How to get the status code from this output?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a small code which uses socket programming to get the HTTP response. What I'm finding difficult is to retrieve the **status code** alone from the response. How should I retrieve it without using any other libraries and also without using any stripping methods?

```
import logging
import socket
import sys

def retrieve_url(url):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("www.google.com", 80))
    s.sendall(b"GET /imghp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n")
    print(s.recv(4096))
    s.close()
    return b'Hello'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(retrieve_url(sys.argv[0]))
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 22 Sep 2019 01:19:14 GMT\r\nExpires: -1\r\nCache-Control: private, max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\nP3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."\r\nServer: gws\r\nX-XSS-Protection: 0\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nSet-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2019-09-22-01; expires=Tue, 22-Oct-2019 01:19:14 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; SameSite=none\r\nSet-Cookie: NID=188=uQ70aAjlLl7g1P0cc
```

and so on.

I need to separately get only the status code(in this case `200` only)

Answer (score 1):

The official Python HTTP library uses the following [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8d4c52ffb47a4d3590758220f297ba58108e1ef3/Lib/http/client.py#L266) to do what you are trying to do:

```py
line = s.recv(4096)

try:
    version, status, reason = line.split(None, 2)
except ValueError:
    try:
        version, status = line.split(None, 1)
        reason = ""
    except ValueError:
        # empty version will cause next test to fail.
        version = ""
if not version.startswith("HTTP/"):
    self._close_conn()
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
```

They are essentially just doing a `.split(None,2)` to split on the first two spaces which in between will be the status.

If you consider this a "*stripping*" method then please let me know what is allowable.

Comment: You could use standard string slicing since it should start at the same place every time. You could regex it out (requires import). You could do a `.find` to find the first space and return the index. Probably more but I'll stop there. @sachinmb27